# android difference between testImplementation and androidTestImplementation in build.gradle

Tags: android, testing, gradle, dependencies

I am using andorid studio 3.2 and I am new to testing. I want to add a testing library but I am not getting what should i write in the dependencies section **testImplentation** or **androidTestImplementation**. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you create android project using Android Studio.
You can find three directories like following. (each directory called [`Source Set`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html))

- app/src/main
- app/src/androidTest : for android UI test. It needs virtual or real device. (Espresso, UI automator)
- app/src/test : for android independent test.

The `androidTest` directory contains test cases that touch the screen or check what is displayed on the screen. 
In the `test` directory, we mainly do `unit tests` such as testing one function.

But test directory is not only for Unit test. You can also write Integration test like HTTP call.
Even you can `UI test` in `test` directory using `Robolectric` library.(It's really fast rather than Espresso)

**So what is `testImplementation` and `androidTestImplementation`? (each called [`Configuration`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html))**

- testImplementation : adds dependency for `test` source set
- androidTestImplementation : adds dependency for `androidTest` source set

---

See this articles for details.

- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library
- https://developer.android.com/studio/test/

Comment: If I need 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0' for both unit test and instrumental test, do I need to include testImplementation and androidTestImplementation for the same library in the gradle dependency

Answer (score 28):

> **implementation**—The dependency is available in **all** source sets, including the test source sets.

> **testImplementation**—The dependency is only available in the test source set.

> **androidTestImplementation**—The dependency is only available in the **androidTest** source set.

Android *source sets* are :

> **main**: Contains your app code. This code is shared amongst all different versions of the app you can build (known as build variants)

> **androidTest**: Contains tests known as instrumented tests.

> **test**: Contains tests known as local tests.

Comment: Dependency that we add for androidTest will increase the size of apk?

Comment: no, test sources are not included in the apk