# AndroidJUnit4.class is deprecated: How to use androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4?

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, androidx

For my instrumentation tests I was using

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
```

from

```
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
```

in order to establish my test cases. Now this line gets marked as deprecated with the hint to use `AndroidJUnit4` from

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
```

However if I try to import `AndroidJUnit4` from the named package I get the error, that `ext` can not be resolved.

Do you have an idea, what package should be included in gradle to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342831/cannot-resolve-symbol-androidjunit4/43342884

Comment: I think your source is obsolet, they do not mention androidx at all.

Comment: Unit testing on Android is an utter mess of bugs and deprecations. The only thing that works for me is creating a new scratch project, copying the relevant files from that project to mine, switching to debug mode, and doing a full cache invalidation. Also for AndroidJUnit4 tests the package name has to match the library package name.

Answer (score 477, accepted):

According to [the documentation for AndroidJUnit4](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnit4),

1. The gradle file should contain the following line:

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'`

2. Change test class to `AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner` from `AndroidJUnit4`

If it still doesn't work, make sure that you clean and/or rebuild your project. Also you can check the current version directly in [Google's maven repository](http://maven.google.com)

Comment: my gradle has this and still cannot resolve the issue.

Comment: @zuko Clean and/or rebuild your project, it should be there. If still not and you're using modules, check that your dependency hierarchy is setup as you expect; you might need to add these to the top level modules too—since testing libraries aren't compiled into shared modules for use by upstream modules.

Comment: @JonAdams my dependency tree kept holding onto a reference to older libraries for some reason even though 
i thought i removed them. so after trying various things i ended up just migrating the project to a new one and everything is fine now.

Comment: Should we also change _testInstrumentationRunner_ in the gradle file from _androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner_ to _androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4_? Just wondering if there's a mismatch.

Comment: @A Droid Replace old AndroidJUnit4 package in import with new one. Just Replace import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
 with import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

Comment: the new package name for AndroidJUnit4 is import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4. If you have your build.app proper , then it has to be an incorrect package name. Note that android studio wont do this on its own. Atleast not the version I am using Android Studio 3.3 updated on Dec 25,2018

Comment: @marcel-gangwisch Where in the linked document does it say to use that dependency?

Comment: @Xplosive you should edit the answer to include your comment

Comment: Had this issue twice when creating new projects and adding 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1' solved it, just remember to remove the old imports from your 'androidTest ' directory and resync project

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that androidTest only builds [for a specific variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#change-the-test-build-type) and that defaults to _debug_. This means it fails to resolve `AndroidJUnit4` when in release mode [unless you switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843734/671393) the target variant. This is mercilessly opaque behaviour.

Comment: As @RupertRawnsley mentioned, using `androidTestImplementation` adds the specified library to the class path for the Debug build variant when running Instrumentation (UI) Tests only. If you are using [`Roboelectric`](http://robolectric.org/) for example you may be attempting to use `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` from local Unit Tests that run using the JVM and do not require the Emulator to be launched. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/)

Answer (score 51):

If you've tried @MarcelGangwisch's solution and your build fails saying it can't find the resource AND you also cleaned/rebuilt your project and it still doesn't work, try this:
(based also on @KrzysztofDziuba's solution)

In your gradle file where you changed the dependency, make sure you are adding it as the type you need, ie.:

For UI tests:

> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'

For Unit tests:

> testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'

In my instance I added it as both and now it works.

Answer (score 26):

For me the following steps worked:
1. Replace the androidx libraries with the one posted [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#gradle-dependencies) . my final `app/build.gradle` looked like this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

    // Espresso dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

I then manually replaced the imported modules in my `ExampleInstrumentTest.java` class with latest classes:

```
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner;
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    ...
    @Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> main = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true);

    @Before
    public void init() {
        ...
    }
    @Test
    public void listCount() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();

        Assert.assertEquals("in.curioustools.aad_x_testing2", appContext.getPackageName());
        System.out.println("useAppContext : Test Ran");
    }
}
```

The thing that was bugging me was the fact that `InstrumentationRegistery` class was still deprecated. So i used `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();` from `androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry` class.

Comment: `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` was the part which got the issue resolved in my case. I don't really get why android studio generates deprecated code sometimes.

Comment: Use `ApllicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()` instead of `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();`

Answer (score 21):

**Solution**

1. Add this line in to build.gradle: `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'`
2. Change `AndroidJUnit4` to `AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner` in the test class

**Warning**

I got the same error, but the following solution failed for me:

File -> Invalidate Caches..., and select Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 10):

I tried all given above until I went to the official Android site,  and they suggested importing from `androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4` instead of `androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4`. [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnit4)

Answer (score 7):

1. Include these lines in build.gradle app module.

   testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
2. In the test class replace your test runner to

   import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
3. If `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` is deprecated use `InstrumentationRegistry` from `androidx.test.platform.app` like this

   InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()

Answer (score 6):

In my case changing `androidTestImplementation` to `testImplementation` helped.
I did't know the difference before reading this [android difference between testImplementation and androidTestImplementation in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076775/android-difference-between-testimplementation-and-androidtestimplementation-in-b)

Answer (score 3):

If you imported those AnroidX test libraries, synced and re-built the project, but the imported packages were still not resolved. Just remember how you upgraded your project to AndroidX, **close Android Studio and remove the `.idea` folder and reopen your project again**...

This worked for me !