# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to firebase and try to implement firebase in next project. I included dependencies as below but it shows the above error. I would be grateful if anyone can provide information.

My builder.gradle(app)files is as follows:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you integrate Firebase into your app, you must choose one of two ways of [adding dependencies, according to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries).  You can either choose to use specific versions of each dependency, like this:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.0'
```

Or, you can use the Firebase BoM to choose them for you, based on a single BoM version that applies specific compatible versions for you:

```
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')

    // versions for Firebase SDKs are chosen automatically by the BoM
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
```

It looks like you tried to use the BoM, but didn't add a line for choosing the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify explicit version numbers like you did it for the other dependencies. For example:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.0'
```

Here you can find more information about the firebase versions --> https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when implementing some Compose UI tests. For me the problem was that the `androidTestImplementation` configuration did not actually have the firebase dependency.

Solved by adding

```
androidTestImplementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx")
```

to the `build.gradle`, along with the previously present

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx")
```

This does not actually make sense, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65873495/6057713). Worked for me though.